# Accessing data from an array that has an INT before it begins

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm pulling data from an API. It comes through as follows:

```
    int(621)
    array(3) {
        ["self"]=>array(1) {["href"]=>string(28) "/inventory?pgsiz=100&pgnum=1"
      }
        ["next"]=>array(1) {["href"]=>string(28) "/inventory?pgsiz=100&pgnum=2"
      }
        ["item"]=>array(1) {["href"]=>string(0) ""
      }
    }
    array(1) {
        ["item"]=>
      array(100) {
        [0]=>
        array(25) {
          ["receiverId"]=>int(1623456)
          ["receivedDate"]=>string(22) "2020-07-27T07:37:43.73"
          ["receiveItemId"]=>int(132576)
          ["customerIdentifier"]=>array(2) { ...
```

Everything I do to try to access the data in `array(100)` fails. I think it's because I'm trying to navigate like it's a multidimensional array, but in reality, the first item in this data isn't an array at all, it's an INT.

How can I skip the `int(621)` as well as the `array(3)` and access `item`?

Edit (print_r)::

```
Array
(
    [totalResults] => 621
    [_links] => Array
        (
            [self] => Array
                (
                    [href] => /inventory?pgsiz=1000&pgnum=1
                )

            [item] => Array
                (
                    [href] => 
                )

        )

    [_embedded] => Array
        (
            [item] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [receiverId] => 1623456
                            [receivedDate] => 2020-07-27T07:37:43.73
                            [receiveItemId] => 1623456
                            [customerIdentifier] => Array ...
```

Comment: Can you show us a simple `print_r($YOUR_ARRAY)` output

Comment: It may be easier to just show us the response from the API without any messing

Comment: It seems as though it's a regular, numerically indexed array. So the integer should be at `[0]`, the next array at `[1]` and so on.

Comment: @RiggsFolly in adding the print_r($YOUR_ARRAY), I did find a foreach() that was occurring as part of the code that connected to the API. I removed this and ran the `print_r`right as it comes from the API.

Comment: @El_Vanja, that's what I thought as well but I keep getting `Undefined offset: 0` when attempting to see what the first item of the array is as a simple test.

Comment: Yeah, after you added the `print_r` result, it showed the missing keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to look at all 100 occurances, so something like this would get you started

```
foreach( $arr['__embedded']['item'] as $occ ) {
    echo $occ['receiverId'];
}
```

> Watch out as `[customerIdentifier]` appears to also be another array, but you have not shown what happens after that so its all yours to explore

Comment: I tried this and I'm getting: `Undefined index: _embeded`.

Comment: I got it, Thank you. Your example missed a "d" in embedded. I'll accept your answer!

Comment: Woops, my mistake. Fixed